# How to concatenate an nsstring url

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, url, nsstring

How can I concatenate an `NSString` URL? For example:

```
http://isomewebsite.com/username=[someuservariable]&password=[somevariable]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with below code.

```
NSString* myURLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"somewebsite.com/username=%@&password=%@", myUserName,myPassword];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:myURLString];
```

Here is the blog tutorial will help you know more about [Handling url authentication challenges accessing password protected servers](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/handling-url-authentication-challenges-accessing-password-protected-servers.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method **stringWithFormat** of NSString:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"somewebsite.com/username=%@&password=%@", someuservariable, some variable];
```

Comment: result = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat: @"http://dev.evsoft.pk/fgglobal/iphone.php?mode=login&u=%@&password=%@",username,password];
but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Don't forget to include the ? between the pathname and query string (and if the server wants it without the ?, I suggest fixing the server, if that's within your power).

Answer (score 0):

Try this excellent post - [URL encoding an NSString on iOS](http://madebymany.com/blog/url-encoding-an-nsstring-on-ios)