# How to concatenate NSURL in Objective-c .?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a NSURL named url where i Have an api that is calling  some movie names. the problem is I want to enter user defined values in it :O 
I have UIsearchBar for text input.
`NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=""&api_key=c4bd8170"];`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741095/how-to-concatenate-an-nsstring-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString *movieName;    //String from UISearchBar
movieName = [movieName stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLUserAllowedCharacterSet]];  //For string with spaces
NSString *movieString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%@&api_key=c4bd8170",movieName];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:movieString];
```

Comment: It works :) thanks Sanket

Comment: glad it helped you :)

Comment: will you please tell your code is working for single word. what should i try to have more than one words with single space.?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%@&api_key=c4bd8170",@"Your user type value"]];
```

Comment: at the end of this query I have to put UISearchBar's text

Comment: yes . replace @"Your user type value" with "your text"

Answer (score 0):

You need to get text of Search bar and encode that text to UTF8.

```
NSString *stringURL = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?query=%@&api_key=c4bd8170", searchBar.text] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
```